# How to use model in config files and controllers without having it in autoload?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

***I don't want to autoload Settings_model*** (in autoload.php) because that model opens a new db connection. It's nothing wrong with that, but it opens a new db-connection for each new object that I create (and that I do NOT want).

Code-snippet for Settings_model:

```
class Settings_model extends CI_Model {

    public static $db_config = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_load_settings();
    }



   /**
     *
     * _load_settings: load the settings from database
     *
     *
     */

    protected function _load_settings() {
    $this->load->library('cache');
    $data = $this->cache->get('settings');
    if (empty($data)) {
        $this->db->select('login_enabled, register_enabled, install_enabled, members_per_page, admin_email, home_page, active_theme,
        login_attempts, recaptcha_theme, email_protocol, sendmail_path, smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_pass, site_title, cookie_expires,
        password_link_expires, activation_link_expires, disable_all, site_disabled_text, remember_me_enabled, recaptcha_enabled');
        $this->db->from('settings');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            $row = $query->row();
            self::$db_config['login_enabled'] = $row->login_enabled;
            self::$db_config['registration_enabled'] = $row->register_enabled;
            self::$db_config['install_enabled'] = $row->install_enabled;

        etc...
```

MY_Controller looks like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (Settings_model::$db_config['disable_all'] == 1 && $this->session->userdata('role_id') != 1 && $this->uri->segment(2) != "login") {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('site_offline');
        }
```

So basically when I create new object:

```
$x = new Object()

**MY_Controller** is called.

Settings_model is called and db-connection are made 
(because $this->load_settings() are called in the constructor).
```

How can I use Settings_model correctly without having to autoload it in the autoload.php?

Yes I could use something like `$this->load->model('system/settings_model')` in each controller, but in some config files it fetches value like this:

```
$config['recaptcha'] = array(
  'public'=>'',
  'private'=>'',
  'RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER' =>'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api',
  'RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER'=>'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api',
  'RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER' =>'www.google.com',
  'RECAPTCHA_SIGNUP_URL' => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create',
  'theme' => Settings_model::$db_config['recaptcha_theme']
);
```

It's quite hard to explain this, but feel free to question if something is unclear.